# Can I use row.add as the InvokeCommand method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, jquery-plugins

In Drupal 8 I want to add a new row to my table in an ajax callback.

```
   $jQuery=new InvokeCommand('#scanned-vouchers', 'row.add', 
    array('','','','','',''));
   $ajax_response->addCommand($jQuery);
```

1) The docs say InvokeCommand supports simple jQuery commands e.g. adClass() etc. if row.add is acceptable how go I pass in the column values via argument 3?

2) If not, what other approach can I use to add a row to the table in the ajax callback bearing in mind  I am using jQuery Databale?

TIA

Ephraim

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a DataTableCommand.php file using the same structure as other files in Drupal/core/Ajax. This file I saved with my custom module.

I hacked misc/ajax.js to process the ajax response. [Not ideal but short on time and now-how to do this correctly].
and now:-

```
   $jQuery=new DataTableCommand('#abc', 'row', 'add', 
    array(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6));
   $ajax_response->addCommand($jQuery);
```

adds a row as expected.